# Marketing Cloud: Sent/Open/Click events in REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am aware that REST API is the modified version of SOAP API. Or soon to be.

My query is: I know how to use an SDK to access Sent/Open/Click events but is it possible to get the same information through REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the REST API Email Studio capabilities are very limited (outside integration with Content Builder) so all of these events are only accessible through the SOAP API.

This is the current documentation on [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/routes.htm) capabilities for reference.